# Why time since measurement on empty function has few nanoseconds error?

Tags: c++

While doing benchmarking on a fast target code that runs in nanoseconds, I found `now()-start` introduces roughly 16ns measurement error on my target machine. Given the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void empty() {}

int main() {
    int n = 1000000;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        std::chrono::nanoseconds since(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            empty();
            since += std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;
        }
        std::cout << "avg since: " << since.count() / n << "ns \n";
    }
}
```

Compile using the following command:

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -O3 -pedantic -Wall main.cpp
```

And runs on `CPU Quad-core Intel Core i7-7700 (-MT-MCP-) speed/max 1341/4200 MHz Kernel 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64`, gets output:

```
avg since: 17ns
avg since: 16ns
avg since: 16ns
avg since: 16ns
avg since: 16ns
avg since: 16ns
avg since: 16ns
avg since: 16ns
avg since: 16ns
avg since: 16ns
```

Why and how to eliminate this type of error source without moving `now()-start` out of the loop? (because it plays the role of stop timer and start timer in actual measurement.)

Comment: I guess that's just your clock interval, i.e. it won't measure any smaller interval.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Good guess. Any ideas to prove it, and what could we do about it?

Comment: calling `now` is not taking `0` time. calling a function even though empty does not take `0` time. In general any measurement comes with an error. Some nanoseconds doesn't sound to bad.

Comment: Just do `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { since -= std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }` and you'll see that there's some overhead in the raw calls too.

Comment: @idclev463035818 With -O3 `empty()` would not even make it to the final assembly

Comment: @NotAProgrammer It doesn't matter. Look at the example I gave above. It doesn't even have `empty();` in it. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/3j398o)

Comment: @NotAProgrammer yep, only noticed `-O3` later. Still there are two calls to `now`, one subtraction and one `+=`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good example. Indeed, say my `empty()` as a target code runs in 10ns, then measuring the code will introduce 16ns error, which is too much. Any idea to eliminate this error source?

Comment: It's not an error. Calling `now()` takes time. What you should usually do to get the average time for the call to your function is to start measuring outside the loop.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not disagreeing with your comment that the calls cost time, just wanted to clarify for other potential readers

Comment: @idclev463035818 I understand that `now()` takes time. But should it be eliminated under measurement, the measurement cares about the time of target code, not the `now()` itself.

Comment: you care about the target code but what you measure does include the call

Comment: you measure between return of first call to `now` and return from second call to `now`, that includes the call to `now`

Comment: @idclev463035818 As I said, it plays the role of stopTimer and startTimer in actual measurement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to measure the average time it takes to call your function, don't sum up the time in the loop. Start measuring outside the loop and stop the counter after it. That way the impact of the overhead of calling `now()` is reduced to *one* call instead of `1000000` calls.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void empty() {}

int main() {
    int n = 1000000;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            empty();
        }
        std::chrono::nanoseconds total = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;

        std::cout << "avg time: " << total.count() / n << "ns \n";
    }
}
```

If you need to keep measuring inside the loop you can reduce the approximate overhead of calling `now()` afterwards. It's inexact and may result in negative values, but it'll give you an idea.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

template<typename Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock>
auto get_now_overhead(size_t n = 10000) {
    auto retval = Clock::now() - Clock::now();
    for(size_t co = 0; co < n; ++co)
        retval = std::max(retval, Clock::now() - Clock::now());
    return -retval; // the minimum overhead found
}

void empty() {}

int main() {
    int n = 1000000;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        std::chrono::nanoseconds since(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            empty();
            since += std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;
        }

        auto overhead = get_now_overhead();
        since -= overhead * n;

        std::cout << "avg since: " << since.count() / n << "ns \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely not the right answer. As I said: "[...] without moving now()-start out of the loop? (because it plays the role of stop timer and start timer in actual measurement.)"

Comment: @Jakob Ok, I missed that part. This is however how you usually measure averages, but I've added an alternative. Note: It's important to calculate `overhead` after the loop. On modern machines, it often takes time for the CPU to spin up so if you measure the overhead at the program start, you'll often get a much larger value than if you do it after the loop.

Comment: maybe also measure not only a single call to `now` but several. The accuracy you get from calling `empty` often is detoriated by the inaccuracy of measuring `now` only once and magnifiying any error by `n`

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, that's a good idea. I added a version to take the minimum overhead found using many measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that `now` is not taking zero time. No matter if `now` returns the exact time when you enter the function or you leave the function, your measurement includes the call to `now`.

Just for the sake of the example, assume the time from `now` is exact for the time point when it returns:

```
time --------------------------------------------->

start call          -----
stop call                                           -----
you measure             ^                               ^
you want to measure      ---------------------------
```

If the time is exact for when you enter `now` the `^     ^` shifts to the left, but on average still contains the time it takes to call `now` once.